# Multiprocessing executing same code multiple times even after lock

Tags: python, flask, multiprocessing, locking, gunicorn

*test.py* is as below, but the `delete` script is running 4 times by 4 workers when I launch the code using `gunicorn -w 4 -b 127.0.0.1:4004 test:app`. But, I want Flask to run on multiple workers and `delete` to run only once:

```py
import multiprocessing
import subprocess
import os
import sys
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from module.delete import run
import logging
from werkzeug.serving import ThreadedWSGIServer

 

logging.basicConfig(
    format='[%(levelname)s][%(asctime)s][PID %(process)d]: (%(filename)s) %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

 

 

lock = multiprocessing.Lock()

 

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

 

ports = {
    'prod': 4004,
    'ppr': 4004,
    'dev': 4004
}
def run_config(lock):
    config = run()

 

    
    lock.acquire()
    try:
        config.run()
    finally:
        lock.release()

 

def manager():

    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    semaphore = manager.Semaphore(1)  # Create a semaphore with a count of 1
    config_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=run_config, args=(semaphore,))
    config_process.daemon = True
    config_process.start()
manager()
class Test(Resource):
    logging.info(f"Resource = {Resource}")
    def post(self):
            with lock:
                 return {'message': 'Payload stored successfully'}, 200

api.add_resource(Test, '/testing')

 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    env = 'master' if len(sys.argv) == 1 else sys.argv[1]
```

Comment: "once lock is released, another worker executes same code again." That's how locks are supposed to work. Once a lock is "released", it isn't "locked" anymore. Other threads\* can lock it. \[\* I have never used `multiprocessing`. I don't know anything about locking in that context specifically. I am just talking about what "lock" means in general.\]

Comment: So conceptually, you want `run_config()` to execute once and only once correct?

Comment: Yes, i want run_config to run once and by one worker only.

Comment: run_config is calling another script which is processing data in database and its non-terminating script, so lock should be acquired in a way that only one processor should do run-config code and rest workers( I am running gunicorn with 3 workers) should do main script task. main script is a flask and takes data and puts in database. so i want flask to be handled by 4 workers.

Comment: It's unclear and unspecific. Post a [mre] with debugging details. Do you want to call the ```config.run()``` only once? Then why not use ```multiprocessing.Value()```? See [this article](https://medium.com/@jgleeee/sharing-data-across-workers-in-a-gunicorn-flask-application-2ad698591875).

Comment: i have added code in question asked for clarity of my doubt

Comment: It's still not a [mre]. It throws an error and contains irrelevant code. If you post a [mre], I'll answer it. Also, you need to write like ```@relent95``` to notify a commentor like me.